# Maven: executable jar does not find resources

Tags: maven, jar, resources

I read several files with:

```
new File(Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResource("Configuration.txt")).getFile());
```

Which works fine for the built project and mvn test, but as soon as I try to execute the jar-file, these calls are null. The files are physically present in the jar. 
What could be wrong here?

My pom-part for building the jar (I have no relevevant dependencies for now):

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>2.4</version>
  <configuration>
  <archive>
      <manifest>
        <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
        <mainClass>path.to.mainclass</mainClass>
      </manifest>
    </archive>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```

The resource files are in the standard folder src/main/resources

Comment: are the files at the root of the Jar, or in the same package as the class?

Comment: The resource files are in the standard folder src/main/resources

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you are using `mvn test` or run tests from IDE you access physical files from your file system but when you are using running jar with packed resources you cannot use `File` class or `getFile()` method. You should use `getClass().getResource()` call or `getClass().getResourceAsStream()`.

Comment: Ok, then how can I list files in a resource directory and how can I write to a file I read through getResourceAsStream()?

Comment: You should not write file to jar file on your classpath (although in some circumstances you are able to do it). You should not try to list entries from the jar files on the classpath. These are the rules of Java platform. Remember that jar file is not the only way to store code and resources.

Comment: Thanks, what would be recommandable instead of a .jar file? Thought about using izPack, would that be a good idea?

Comment: JAR file is OK for classes and static resources. Configuration files and other writable stuff should be elsewhere. An installer that would keep all of this together is a good idea.